# Thread-safe intrusive_ptr

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

The `boost::intrusive_ptr` (or a home-made version) at its simplest looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
class intrusive_ptr {
public:
    intrusive_ptr(T* ptr) : ptr_(ptr)
    {
        if (ptr_) {
            intrusive_ptr_add_ref(ptr_);
        }
    }

    intrusive_ptr(const intrusive_ptr& that) : ptr_(that.ptr_)
    {
        if (ptr_) {
            intrusive_ptr_add_ref(ptr_);
        }
    }

    ~intrusive_ptr()
    {
        if (ptr_) {
            intrusive_ptr_release(ptr_);
        }
    }

    // ...

private:
    ptr_;
};
```

Usage:

```
class Foo {
public:
    // ...

private:
    std::size_t refcount_;

    friend void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(const Foo* p)
    {
        ++p->refcount_;
    }

    friend void intrusive_ptr_release(const Foo* p)
    {
        if (--p->refcount_ == 0) {  // line 1
            delete p;               // line 2
        }
    }
};

intrusive_ptr<Foo> p(new Foo);
```

Apparently as `Foo` is implemented now, `intrusive_ptr<Foo>`s aren't thread-safe. Simply changing the type of `Foo::refcount_` to `std::atomic<std::size_t>` won't suffice either, because when one thread is between line 1 and line 2, another thread may try to increase the reference count.

So my question is: Is it possible to make `intrusive_ptr` thread-safe, ideally without resorting to heavy mechanisms like mutexes?

Comment: What about thread level locality?

Comment: @M4rc Could you elaborate?

Comment: AFAIK boost thread has something along the lines of thread_local as a specifier (or perhaps class -- apologies, I'm running a distro build and computer is too laggy to search it). If you declare it thread local (either with `boost thread local`, or `__thread` each intrusive_ptr would exist only to that thread, keeping them separate. Or must these two pointers be accessible from other threads?

Comment: A mutex might not be too heavy... have you profiled? Things like this are weird with atomic because of the multi-operation implication (decrement, compare, do something). You might be able to hack something together with `compare_exchange_strong` but that's out of my area of expertise.

Comment: @M4rc *Or must these two pointers be accessible from other threads?* Yes, my goal is to make the `intrusive_ptr` an atomic entity as seen by multiple threads.

Comment: @AndyG I think as Jeremy answered below, if I make sure I'm only handling around `intrusive_ptr`s (instead of raw pointers), using an atomic counter should suffice.

Comment: Mutexes are probably the way to go.

Comment: FWIW my apps all use atomic, intrusive reference counting pointers to manage the lifetime of C++ heap objects that are shared across threads, and it works great -- it avoids any risk of deadlocks or memory leaks.  (You do still have to worry about race conditions when changing the state of the objects of course, but that's a separate issue)

Comment: Andrei Alexandrescu had some thoughts and slides on this talk: https://youtu.be/Qq_WaiwzOtI?t=34m30s , ahh, nvm, its a single-thread-ptr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is: Is it possible to make intrusive_ptr thread-safe,
>   ideally without resorting to heavy mechanisms like mutexes?

Yes.  Changing the counter to std::atomic will suffice, because if thread A reduces the counter value to zero, then it is guaranteed that no other intrusive_ptr<> objects are pointing to object p.  (Because if any did exist, the refcount value would still be greater than zero).

So the race condition you're worrying about can't happen.  (Well, it could happen if some other thread was dereferencing a raw pointer to object p, rather than holding an intrusive_ptr, but in that case all bets are off anyway because the program is buggy)

Comment: I guess the problem is not only *dereferencing a raw pointer to object p*, but also trying to reconstruct an `intrusive_ptr` from a raw pointer?

Comment: Yes, that could cause a problem, since if you have only a raw pointer and other threads might at any time delete the object that pointer points to, you can't guarantee that your raw pointer is pointing to a valid object.  It might well have been deleted even a long time before you try to increment the object's ref count.  The best solution there is not to hold a raw pointer, but pass around intrusive_ptrs instead (or use some other mechanism to ensure the object is valid)

Answer (score 1):

You could choose to detect pointer-theft:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdexcept>

struct allow_zero_access {};

template<typename T>
class intrusive_ptr {
public:

    intrusive_ptr(T* ptr, allow_zero_access)
    : ptr_(ptr)
    {
      assert(ptr);
      intrusive_ptr_init_ref(ptr_, allow_zero_access());
    }

    intrusive_ptr(T* ptr) : ptr_(ptr)
    {
        if (ptr_) {
            intrusive_ptr_add_ref(ptr_);
        }
    }

    intrusive_ptr(const intrusive_ptr& that) : ptr_(that.ptr_)
    {
        if (ptr_) {
            intrusive_ptr_add_ref(ptr_);
        }
    }

    intrusive_ptr& operator=(const intrusive_ptr& that)
    {
      intrusive_ptr tmp(that);
      std::swap(this->ptr_, tmp.ptr_);
      return *this;
    }

    ~intrusive_ptr()
    {
        if (ptr_) {
            intrusive_ptr_release(ptr_);
        }
    }

    // ...

private:
    T* ptr_;
};

template<class T>
struct enable_mt_intrusive_pointer
{
  private:
    friend void intrusive_ptr_init_ref(const enable_mt_intrusive_pointer* p, allow_zero_access)
    {
      assert(p);
      if (p->_refcount.fetch_add(1) != 0) {
        throw std::logic_error("stealing someone's pointer!");
      }
    }

  friend void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(const enable_mt_intrusive_pointer* p, bool first_access = false)
    {
      assert(p);
      if (p->_refcount.fetch_add(1) == 0 && !first_access) {
        throw std::logic_error("resurrecting a zombie");
      }
    }

    friend void intrusive_ptr_release(const enable_mt_intrusive_pointer* p)
    {
      assert(p);
      switch(p->_refcount.fetch_sub(1)) {
        case 1:
          delete p;
          break;
        case 0:
          throw std::logic_error("already deleted");
          break;
        default:
          ;
      }
    }

    mutable std::atomic<std::size_t> _refcount { 0 };
};

template<class T, class...Args>
intrusive_ptr<T> make_intrusive_ptr(Args&&...args)
{
  return { new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...),
           allow_zero_access() };
}



class Foo : public enable_mt_intrusive_pointer<Foo>
{
public:
    // ...

};

int main()
{
    auto p = make_intrusive_ptr<Foo>();
}
```

However, in practice there is rarely a reason to use intrusive_ptr's in a c++ program. Even when interfacing with external c libraries, the otherwise intrusive pointers can be wrapped in a std::shared_ptr with a custom deleter.

Comment: Do you intend to do the swap in `operator=(const intrusive_ptr& that)`?

Comment: @ZizhengTai no. I conflated the move assignment with the assignment. it's late...